# calling filter on list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list that is dynamically populated using ng-repeat. The list consists of a thumbnail and a title.

The filter works fine, however, the thumbnails are not once the filter is used and reset. The reason for this is when I load my thumbnails, I load from a CDN that requires a specific hashed URL that I can set to be alive for X amount of seconds. In my case, I keep the link alive for 10 seconds. Plenty of time to load a tiny thumbnail.

Filter appears to be reloading the image (with the hashed URL) when resetting the filter. The problem is by this time, the URL is no longer valid. Is there a way to change `filter` to set the visibility of a list item to none rather than completely removing it and having to reload the object?

My code is below

```
<ul id="list" class="unstyled">
  <li ng-repeat="slide in data | filter:searchQuery">
    <span class="thumbnail glow" style="background: url({{currentThumb}})" index="{{$index}}" sprite-thumb></span>
    <span class="listItemText">
      <b>{{slide.slideIndex + 1}}. </b>{{slide.title}}
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No I believe the problem is the interpolation with the expression {{currentThumb}} is going to re-evaluate during a digest which has to occur when the filter changes the array to show.  ng-show and ng-hide toggle the display from whatever the default is to none and back and ng-if removes an element conditionally but either way if the value is bound I think it's going to trigger a refresh in the view.

Comment: @shaunhusain oh, I think you are right. Do you have any ideas on how can I avoid this?

Comment: nevermind. I figured it out. My directive on the thumbnail `sprite-thumb` is causing the issue and I believe I can remedy this.

Comment: ok please post as an answer if you get it resolved in case I'm wrong here I'd like to know too.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was with my `sprite-thumb` directive. In the directive, I had an `$observe` watching the `style` attr and when the list would filter the `$observe` function would get fired again.

I decided to ditch the directive and rather than `style="background: url({{currentThumb}})"`

I am explicitly using `ng-style` like this:

`ng-style="{'background-image' : 'url(' + currentThumb + ')', 'background-position' : getSpriteStyle(slide.slideIndex)}"`

`getSpriteStyle()` is :

```
$scope.getSpriteStyle = function(id)
{
    return '0 ' + -(id * 80) + 'px';
}
```

that function sets that `background-position` property on the `background-image`